# Core Java implementation for authorization code flow using Azure AD

Tags: java, azure

**Client credential grant type:**

```
String url = https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantID}//oauth/v2.0/token; 
Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
parameters.put("grant_type", "client_credentials");
parameters.put("client_id", "CLIENT_ID");
parameters.put("client_secret","CLIENT_SECRET");
parameters.put("scope", CLIENT_ID/.default);

 String form = parameters.keySet().stream()
        .map(key -> key + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(parameters.get(key), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
        .collect(Collectors.joining("&"));

HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(URI.create(url))
        .headers("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded").POST(BodyPublishers.ofString(form))
        .build();
HttpResponse<?> response = null;
try {
    response = client.send(request, BodyHandlers.ofString());
} catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Response will have access token.

**Authorization Code grant type**

Without any browser interaction, would like to pass credential from the code to get access token.

As I understand first we need to make GET call to get access code then POST call to get access token.

```
Auth URL = https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantID}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
Access Token URL=https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantID}/oauth2/v2.0/token
Client ID={ClientID} Client Secret={Client_Secret}
Scope={ClientID}/.default
Grant Type= Authorization code
Callback URL : http//redirectURL
```

Having above details able to test token generation with POSTMAN.

I would like to know how to achieve same using java code without using the spring boot.

Is it possible to achieve get access token without browser.

Answer (score 0):

*I tried the below Authorization code to get the access token from Azure Active Directory in Java.*

**Code :**

```java
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class AuthorizationCodeFlow {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String authUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_ID>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize";
        String clientId = "<client_ID>";
        String redirectUri = "http://localhost:8080";
        String scope = clientId + "/.default";

        startHttpServer();
        String authorizationUrl = authUrl + "?client_id=" + clientId +
                "&redirect_uri=" + URLEncoder.encode(redirectUri, StandardCharsets.UTF_8) +
                "&response_type=code" +
                "&scope=" + URLEncoder.encode(scope, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        System.out.println("Authorization URL: " + authorizationUrl);
        System.out.println("Waiting for the authorization code...");

        String authCode = waitForAuthorizationCode();
        System.out.println("Authorization Code: " + authCode);

        String tokenUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_ID>/oauth2/v2.0/token";
        String clientSecret = "<client_secret>";  
        String accessToken = exchangeAuthCodeForAccessToken(tokenUrl, clientId, clientSecret, redirectUri, authCode);
        System.out.println("Access Token: " + accessToken);
    }

    private static void startHttpServer() throws IOException {
        int port = 8080;
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(port), 0);
        server.createContext("/", new MyHandler());
        server.setExecutor(null); 
        server.start();
    }

    private static String waitForAuthorizationCode() throws InterruptedException {
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        CallbackHandler.setLatch(latch);
        latch.await(); 
        return CallbackHandler.getAuthorizationCode();
    }

    static class MyHandler implements HttpHandler {
        @Override
        public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {
            String query = t.getRequestURI().getQuery();
            Map<String, String> queryParams = parseQuery(query);
            String authCode = queryParams.get("code");

            String response = "Authorization code received. You can close this window.";
            t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
            OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
            os.write(response.getBytes());
            os.close();

            CallbackHandler.setAuthorizationCode(authCode);
            CallbackHandler.getLatch().countDown();
        }
    }

    private static Map<String, String> parseQuery(String query) {
        if (query == null || query.isEmpty()) {
            return new HashMap<>();
        }

        return Stream.of(query.split("&"))
                .map(s -> s.split("="))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        arr -> arr[0],
                        arr -> arr.length > 1 ? arr[1] : ""
                ));
    }

    private static String exchangeAuthCodeForAccessToken(String tokenUrl, String clientId, String clientSecret, String redirectUri, String authCode) {
        Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
        parameters.put("grant_type", "authorization_code");
        parameters.put("client_id", clientId);
        parameters.put("client_secret", clientSecret);
        parameters.put("code", authCode);
        parameters.put("redirect_uri", redirectUri);

        String form = parameters.keySet().stream()
                .map(key -> key + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(parameters.get(key), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
                .collect(Collectors.joining("&"));

        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create(tokenUrl))
                .headers("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(form))
                .build();

        try {
            HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
            return response.body();
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}

class CallbackHandler {
    private static String authorizationCode;
    private static CountDownLatch latch;

    public static String getAuthorizationCode() {
        return authorizationCode;
    }

    public static void setAuthorizationCode(String code) {
        authorizationCode = code;
    }

    public static CountDownLatch getLatch() {
        return latch;
    }

    public static void setLatch(CountDownLatch latch) {
        CallbackHandler.latch = latch;
    }
}
```

I have added the below URL in the app **Redirect Web URI**  and selected the **access token** as below,

> http://localhost:8080

[image]
[image]

**Output :**

It ran successfully. I copied the **Authorization URL** from the output as below,

[image]

*And pasted the Authorization URL in the browser for Login with my Azure account as below,*

[image]

I logged in successfully as below,

[image]

***I got the authorization code with the access token from the Azure Active Directory as below.***

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for above code and with detailed explanation and it works perfectly.  Is there way to authorize from the code instead of pasting the url in browser to get authorization code.

Comment: @Mahajan I have updated the code instead of pasting the **URL** in the browser to get the **authorization code**.

Comment: Thank you for again sharing modified code, when I execute program it get stopped are Waiting for the authorization code... message, where do I need to provide username/password to authenticate to proceed with further steps. Am I doing anything wrong here. I would like to pass username/password to authorize without using browser.

Comment: Is it possible to authenticate with MFA from code instead of using browser.

Comment: @Mahajan To automate the authentication process without user interaction or to handle MFA programmatically, you may want to explore other authentication flows.

Comment: @Mahajan The Resource Owner Password Credentials (ROPC) grant is one such flow that allows you to exchange a username and password for tokens directly. Still, it has some security implications and is generally not recommended.